# express.raw is not a function Node.js Express with Stripe

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, payment-processing

I am getting this error when trying to use express.raw() as a middleware with stripe. I am following the stripe documentation and did exactly as they said.

```
const express = require('express')

//other stuff

router.post(
  "/webhook",
  express.raw({ type: "application/json" }),
  function (request, response) {
    const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];

    console.log(request.body);

    let event;

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        request.body,
        sig,
        process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    }

    response.status(200).end();
  }
);
```

**Specifications**

- I am not using body parser just express.json()
- I am using stripe and following [webhooks on stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart?shell=true)

Any help in the positive direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `express.raw()` function was added in Express v4.17.0 per [this doc](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.raw). Based on the error you get it's likely that you are using an older version of Express and would need to upgrade. If you can't upgrade you might have to rely on [body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) instead.

Note that verifying signature with Stripe's webhooks can be quite complex as the right configuration depends on your exact version of Express and how you configured the root. You can also look at [this Github issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/341) on stripe-node where a lot of developers have shared what worked for their own configuration specifically.

Comment: Thank You. For me the problem was, I was declaring express.json() and after that express.raw() which obviously don't work at the same time